# Security Policy prevents video recording

Tags: samsung, security, video-recording

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5. A few weeks ago, my video camera stopped working. Every time I press the video button, the following message appears:

> Security Policy prevents video recording

I have tried every recommendation, but I am still seeing this notice.

How can I get rid of this issue to record again?

Comment: Do you have an Exchange or corporate email account on your device?

Comment: @AbandonedCart AFAIK, the Security Policy will prevent the feature completely, so I don't think it's possible to get rid of the notification and record a video without disabling/bypassing the policy altogether. But fair point, perhaps there's a way to do it without disabling it.

Comment: @AndrewT. Even so, it should be left to the person answering to decide if that is the best route to take without changing the question to ask for it. 90% of the time a question seems to have such an obvious process, that is the process that was already tried and failed.

Answer (score 1):

A Security Policy can come from a few different sources, so it depends on where yours originated.

If it is a company device, you may not have any options without asking for permission.

If you have a Microsoft Exchange account, you would likely need to remove the account.

If it is your personal device and you do not have an Exchange account:

- Go to Settings -> More -> Application Manager (or Settings -> Apps on Samsung)
- Select the All item
- Scroll down and tap on Security Policy Update
- Press Force Quit
- Press Clear Data
- Restart your phone

Credit for this process goes to [skippybosco's reply on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/galaxynote4/comments/5sw5bz/security_policy_restricts_use_of_camera_message/)

Comment: on Samsung phone there is no provision to select all apps and further the said steps....

Comment: @Shamshu Not entirely sure what you were trying to post, but this process may not apply beyond Marshmallow (the last version for an S5, per the question)

Answer (score 0):

Check if [Sensors Off](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensors-off) is enabled on the quick settings panel.

[image]

It might also be a reason why your camera won't work.

Comment: I don't see this button on Pixel 3a. Is this on Samsung (as per question)? Otherwise, could you mention the device model and Android version?

Comment: I'm using Android 12 on Galaxy Note 10+. However, it needs developer mode to be visible.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for the info. Apparently, it's also available on Pixel 3a, Android 12. I just did some tests with this setting and video recording, and while it's true that I can't see anything from the camera, I didn't get any message about "Security Policy". Though, I don't know if it behaves differently or not on Samsung/other devices.